# Does Microsoft Band SDK support a UWP app on windows 10 iot pulling data from the Band?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, microsoft-band, windows-10-iot-core

I want to pull sensor data from the band using a UWP app on windows 10 iot raspberry pi. The app runs perfectly when running on windows 10 machine however, when running on windows 10 iot, it shows errors.

The execution breaks in an auto generated code in file App.g.i.cs:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }; 
#endif
```

In call stack it shows:

> FFM.exe!FFM.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__5_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 53  C#

Line 53 is of the auto generated code:

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Debug output shows following:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

The band is able to connect to windows 10 iot Raspi but as soon as there is code that asks for user consent to access heartrate sensor data, the above errors start showing.

Following is my code to get user consent. Much of it is from the band SDK Documentation:

```
private async void connect()
{
    //Get a list of paired bands
    IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
    string band_name = pairedBands[0].Name;
    if (band_name.Length > 0)
    {
        bandName.Text = "Band Name is: " + band_name;
        try
        {
            fwVer.Text = "Will try to connect to band";
            IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]);

            fwVer.Text = "Connected to Band";

            fwVersion = await bandClient.GetFirmwareVersionAsync();
            hwVersion = await bandClient.GetHardwareVersionAsync();

            fwVer.Text = "Firmware Version is " + fwVersion;
            hwVer.Text = "Hardware Version is " + hwVersion;

            string band1v = "9";
            if (hwVersion.Equals(band1v, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                // Do work with Version 1 of the band
                bandVer.Text = "Band is Version 1";

                //User consent check to use heartbeat sensor data
                if (bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.GetCurrentUserConsent() != UserConsent.Granted)
                {     
                    //Get user consent
                    await bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.RequestUserConsentAsync();
                }   
                if (bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.GetCurrentUserConsent() == UserConsent.Granted)
                {
                    //DO work
                }
                else
                {
                    hrConsent.Text = "Access to HeartReat sensor is denied";
                }
            }
            else //Its a 2nd version of band
            {
                //Do work with version 2 of the band
                bandVer.Text = "Band is Version 2";
            }
        }
        catch (BandException ex)
        {
            //handle a band connection exception
            fwVer.Text = "Could not connect to above band";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bandName.Text = "No Available Bands";
    }
}
```

Following are the libraries I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

using Microsoft.Band;
using Microsoft.Band.Sensors;
using Microsoft.IoT;

using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
```

Answer (score 2):

When the application calls `RequestUserConsentAsync()` the Band SDK displays a dialog message to the user to obtain that consent.  However, it appears that `Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog` is not yet supported by Windows IoT Core (see [unavailable API list](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/UnavailableApis.htm)).

That may be the cause of the exception.